# C#: list of <T> of = list of <Derived from T> doesn't compile

Tags: c#

I've got a base Class ScenBase and a derived class ScenC. I have a class HexC derived form the base class Hex. I also have a class UnitC derived from the base class Unit. I can set an array of Hex to point to an array of HexC, but the compiler won't let me set a List of Unit to point to a list of UnitC:

```
// The Core Database for the game scenario.
// Theoretically multiple secenarios can be loaded
// into memory at the same time.
[Serializable]
public class ScenC : ScenBase
{
    public bool playable { get; set; }
    public HexC[,] hexCs { get; private set; }
    public List<UnitC> unitCs { get; private set; }

    // A database for every user and AI entity.
    public List<ScenV> chViews { get; private set; }
    public List<string> characters { get; private set; }

    public ScenC(int xDimI, int yDimI) : base (xDimI, yDimI)
    {
        playable = false;
        chViews = new List<ScenV>();
        characters = new List<string>();
        characters.Add("Supreme");
        hexCs = new HexC[xDim, yDim];
        hexs = hexCs;                //this line complies fine
        newHex = (int x, int y) => new HexC(this, x,  y);
        unitCs = new List<UnitC>();

        // **This line won't compile**
        unitCs = units;
        Init();
    }
}
```

Here are the fields properties for the base class ScenBase:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ScenBase
{
    public Hex[,] hexs;
    public List<Unit> units { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime currGameTime { get; set; }
    public int xDim { get; set; }
    public int yDim { get; set; }
    public double scale { get; protected set; }
    protected delegate Hex NewHex(int x, int y);
    protected NewHex newHex;

    //Rest of Class not shown for simplicity
}
```

Why Can't I set a `List<Hex>` to a `List<HexC>` when that follows the "is a" implicit cast rule, but I can set array to array

Comment: Covariance on classes is not supported in C#. And on collections it isn't typesafe either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.

Had it been possible, you would have been able to add a different derived type to the list.
For example:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>
List<Vehicle> vehicles = cars;   //Error!
vehicles.Add(new Bicycle());     //That's not a car!
```

What you're asking for is called *covariance*; it's only possible for immutable interfaces (such as `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: Ah I see. Its adding elements later that makes it type unsafe. I guess its OK to set an array of T to point to an array of derived from T because array elements are normally declared once and not added to later. I was thinking of making the ScenBase class generic anyway, but I'm glad I asked the question because now I can see the reasoning behind the language rules.

Comment: @Rich: Your guess is wrong.  Array covariance is unsafe, and is only allowed for legacy reasons.  Because they are covariant, arrays need to check for type compatibility at runtime.

Comment: So is it generally best to minimize the use of arrays and use generic collections instead? I could create a custom generic collection for the two dimensional hex array and create my own iterator so it could be accessed like a 2 dimensional array

Answer (score 1):

you could use a list of interfaces (1) where the Hex and Unit conform to the nominated interface in some way.  otherwise, you will need to cast.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465120.aspx

btw: any interface of IEnumerable is already covariant (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx).  Syntax: the *out* in IEnumerable<*out* T> defines covariance.

**(1) A list of interface**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IHex {
    string ToString();
}

public class Hex : IHex
{
    public override string ToString() { return "Hex"; } 
} 

public interface IHexC : IHex {}
public class HexC : Hex
{
    public override string ToString() { return "HexC"; } 
}

public class Test{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<IHex> HexList = new List<IHex>();

        HexList.Add(new Hex());
        HexList.Add(new HexC());
        HexList.Add(new HexC());

        foreach(var o in HexList){
            Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Console output:**

Hex

HexC

HexC

---

Comment: You can't make an explicit or implicit type conversion to a List.

Comment: came up with a better example for you.  List<IInterface> gets around that.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible like SLaks said, you could use an interface instead. `IList<IHex>` for example...

Answer (score 0):

you can't cast a

```
   List<UnitC> // UnitC - to a derived from a Unit class
```

to a

```
    List<Unit> // Unit - the base class
```

try with a IUnit interface instead

Answer (score 0):

A general point to consider, in addition to SLaks' explanation as to why your code doesn't work is that using a generic defines a new type:

```
Unit is a type.
UnitC is a type derived from Unit.

List<Unit> is a new type.
List<UnitC> is a new type, but is not derived from List<Unit>.
```

However,

```
Hex[] defines multiple instances of the Hex type.
HexC[] defines multiple instances of the HexC type (which is derived from Hex).
```

Your assignment doesn't work because the compiler can't ensure that the elements of units are actually instances of UnitC, but if you attempted the inverse (units = unitCs), that wouldn't work, either, because List < UnitC > isn't derived from List < Unit >.